# Is it possible to change the default of F1-F8 keys from media to regular function keeping the F9-F12 as is on Dell XPS 15?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, windows-11, dell-xps

I know there that you can switch between FN and Media via Fn+Esc. I know there are BIOS options to change the default for the whole row.
But what I want is to only change in for F10-F12. I rarely use these keys for their original purpose, however dell has placed important functions like Home and End on those, which I use frequently. Contrarily, I often use F1-F8 in all sorts of hot keys action, so I'd like to keep them as their non-media version. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's all or nothing.

Comment: @ChanganAuto that sucks. Can't you at least do something with 3rd party apps, like ahk?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I was able to solve this using KeyTweak utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired outcome using KeyTweak utility. Just remapped Fn+F1x to F1x and vice versa using Full Teach Mode.

[image: KetWeak example]